# Android - toolbar doesn't show anything

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar, android-toolbar

my toolbar doesn't show anything. Everything seems fine but it doesn't work. Even when I add title, toolbar doesn't show it. It only changes color when I change it in acivity_basic.xml. Thanks

Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".BasicActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

BasicActivity.java

```
rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_basic, null);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.basic_toolbar);
    if(toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My custom toolbar!");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

onCreateOptionMenu in BasicActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_basic, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

acivity_basic.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_basic"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.sloth.BasicActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/basic_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>
```

menu_basic.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".BasicActivity">


<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Menu"
    >
</item>
```

Comment: Obviously you should uncomment toolbar part in layout.

Comment: Activities typically  use setContentView, not getting a LayoutInflater. Are you actually using a Fragment??

Comment: It's an activity, I have setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic); above getMenuInflater

Comment: @Yuro8 So what's the purpose of using `LayoutInflater` if you already have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic)` ?

Comment: I don't now, BUT you are right! It's working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for my project. I wrapped an AppBarLayout (with a coordinatorLayout) around the toolbar in the XML. and I return true for onCreateOptionsMenu instead of calling super.onCreateOptionsMenu()

The rest of my codes look similar to what you currently have. you can try to see if it helps.

in MainActivity's onCreate() method

```
if(toolbar !=null){
    toolbar.setSubtitle("My Toolbar"); 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Actionbar abar = getSupportActionbar();
    if(aBar !=null){
        aBar.setDisplayHomeAsEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

in mainActivity's onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search); 
    ... my custom handling for mi (change color, hide/show specific mi, etc).

    return true; 
}
```

in my Activity XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout... >
    ... rest of stuff
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.Coordinatorlayout>
```